# cannot inject falcor in angular app

Tags: angularjs, falcor

I am using browserify in my angular app. I read some articles about falcor and decided to test but I have issue injecting it in my app. So I installed falcor via npm and I am trying to inject it like this:

```
require('falcor');

var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.router', 'login', 'falcor'];
```

But I receive: `Failed to instantiate module falcor due to` error.

Later on in my service my idea is to do something like this:

```
app.service('loginService', function(falcor) {
  function falcor() {
        var model = new falcor.Model({
            cache: {
                events: [
                    {
                        name: "ng-conf",
                        description: "The worlds best Angular Conference",
                        location: { city: "Salt Lake City", state: "Utah" }
                    },
                    {
                        name: "NodeConf",
                        description: "NodeConf is the longest running community driven conference for the Node community.",
                        location: { city: "Walker Creek Ranch", state: "California" }
                    }

                ]
            }
        });

        model
        // We want the name and description values for the first three items
        // from the data model
            .get(["events", {from: 0, to: 2}, ["name", "description"]])
            .then(function(response) {

            });
    }

     return {
          falcor: falcor
     }
});
```

So my question is how to correctly inject falcor so I can use it in my app? There are almost no examples about using angular with falcor so I am rather stuck.

I found a npm package- ng-falcor but as there are no examples only some basic description on the api I decided to skip it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The falcor library does not contain an Angular module named `falcor`. Remove that from your module's dependencies: `angular.module('app', ['ui.router', 'login'];`. This will not prevent you from using the `falcor` global.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that it dosent find the module 'falcor' is because you didnt give the script to go to... So in your index.html file add this:

```
<script src="https://netflix.github.io/falcor/build/falcor.browser.js"></script>
```

So then now when you run it, it knows what falcor is, so it can run it! Hope this helped!

Comment: I do not need to include reference to falcor in my index.html file. I have installed falcor with npm and it is in my node_packages. I load it via require('falcor') statement as stated in the example.